# Javascript - Time Return Attribute

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code and not having much luck in getting a return attribute for just the hour, minutes and seconds.

Would appreciate if somebody could provide me some pointers.

```
 function XMASClock(){

        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds(); 
        return [ h, m, s ].join(':')

        alert(today);
    }
```

Regards
Chris

Comment: Works fine — http://jsbin.com/newekihegi/1/ — What's the problem?

Comment: @Quentin - You got me, I couldn't believe the alert worked, until I noticed you added another alert for the returned content.

Comment: The *alert* after the *return* doesn't get called. You need to do something with the return value (as Quentin has done), e.g. `alert(XMASClock());`. ;-)

Comment: The alert in this function will never run but logic seems fine

Comment: Missing semicolon on the `return` Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function XMASClock(){

        var today = new Date(),
         h = today.getHours(),
         m = today.getMinutes(),
         s = today.getSeconds(); /*variable declaration*/

        today = [ h, m, s ].join(':'); /*pass the new value of today */

        alert(today); /*this is what you are looking for*/

        return today

        
}

XMASClock();
```